# Unhashable type: list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, hashable

I am working on a program that parses through log files and returns the top hits for IP addresses and a couple other things. Currently I am having trouble and I cannot interpret any of the answers to this problem to what I have going on right now. This is all of my code:

```
import gzip
from collections import Counter
logFileName = open('C:\\Users\\Pawlaczykm\\Desktop\\fileNames.txt', 'r')
ipAdd = []
landingPages = []
ALL_ipAdd = []
ALL_landingPages = []
# everything after this line gets done to all files
for line in logFileName.readlines():
# rstrip removes a blank line from output
# print 'Summary of: ' + line.rstrip()

# use gzip to decompress the file
with gzip.open('C:\\Users\\Pawlaczykm\\Desktop\\logFiles\\' + line.rstrip() + '.gz', 'rb') as f:
    # we extract the ip addresses in lines 15-18
    for eachLine in f:
        parts = eachLine.split('\t')
        if len(parts) > 1:
            ipAdd.append(parts[2])
ALL_ipAdd.append(ipAdd)
# use gzip to decompress the file
with gzip.open('C:\\Users\\Pawlaczykm\\Desktop\\logFiles\\' + line.rstrip() + '.gz', 'rb') as f:
    # we extract the landing pages
    for eachLine in f:
        parts = eachLine.split('\t')
        if len(parts) > 1:
            variable = parts[8].split('?')[0]
            landingPages.append(variable)
v): (-v, k))[:10]
ALL_landingPages.append(landingPages)

ALL_ipAddDict = dict(Counter(ALL_ipAdd).most_common())
sortedALL_ipAdd = sorted(ALL_ipAddDict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): (-v,     k))[:10]
print 'Top IPs of all files'
print(sortedALL_ipAdd)
ALL_LandingPageDict = dict(Counter(ALL_landingPages).most_common())
sortedALL_LandingPage = sorted(ALL_LandingPageDict.iteritems(), key=lambda     (k, v): (-v, k))[:10]
print 'Top landing pages of all files'
print (sortedALL_LandingPage)
```

Now where I am having trouble is in the following line:

```
ALL_ipAddDict = dict(Counter(ALL_ipAdd).most_common())
```

The output when I run the whole program is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Pawlaczykm/PycharmProjects/LogParse/parseText.py", line 35, in <module>
    ALL_ipAddDict = dict(Counter(ALL_ipAdd).most_common())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\collections.py", line 477, in __init__
self.update(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\collections.py", line 567, in update
self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
 TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can somebody help me? This is frustrating.

Comment: lists are mutable and therefore not hashable. as a result they cannot be used as keys in dictionaries

Comment: Can you show us what's inside `ALL_ipAdd`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Is there a way I can take a list, turn that into a dictionary, and then hash the dictionary?

Comment: @mattp341 you can convert your `list` to a `tuple` before using it as a dictionary key

Comment: @StevenRumbalski given there's only a single list in`All_ipAdd` that solution would work given only the first slice `{key:val for key, val in Counter(ALL_ipAdd[0]).most_common()}`

Answer (score 4):

From your code `ALL_ipAdd = []` and `ipAdd = []` and `ALL_ipAdd.append(ipAdd)` we can conclude that `ALL_ipAdd` is a list of list.  `Counter` is a subtype of `dict`, which hashes its items before it counts them.  Lists cannot be hashed because they are mutable (if the list changed the hash would change) and thus lists can't be counted by `Counter` objects.

To solve this you can convert the inner lists to tuples before counting them:

```
ALL_ipAddDict = dict(Counter(map(tuple, ALL_ipAdd)).most_common())
```

Answer (score -2):

That's normal. `ALL_ipAdd` is a list of lists. `Counter` needs a list, a string or any other hashable type :)